# viewing my virtualbox redhat's localhost to my virtualbox winxp browser

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, windows-xp, redhat, virtualbox

I have a [redhat](http://www.redhat.com/)(virtualbox) localhost working and everything,
and a winxp(virtualbox), i want to view the localhost what i made in redhat
in windows xp i got the ip via `/sbin/ifconfig`

```
inet addr:10.0.0.1
bcast 10.0.0.255
```

typed it in winxp
bit it didn't work also tryed the bdcast but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both XP and redhat are Virtual Machines, make sure the virtual network cards are configured to use bridged network. Read more about this at http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: both redhat and winxp now has a bridged network but no luck :(

Comment: After switching to bridged networking, you will need to restart networking. In the case of bridged configuration, you will get an IP in the same range as your host machine(make sure you have a dhcp server on your LAN).

Comment: You can also choose "Host-only networking" for both VMs and restart networking. You should get a 192.168.56.X IP.

Comment: i selected "Host-only networking" for both virtual machines, but under naam: it says "not selected", and when I click it i get a dropdown menu, but nothing else is available but the "not selected" option???